# Minimal sample size for Granger causality testing with quarterly macroeconomic data

Tags: sample-size, vector-autoregression, granger-causality, macroeconomics

I would like to operate a Granger causality for employment and growth rate from the first quarter of 2000 to the fourth quarter of 2013.

Can I do that? Is the time period too short? What is the minimum number of years (especially in monthly-quarterly data) required to operate VAR and Granger causality?

Comment: What do you think about the answer? So far you have neither accepted it nor commented on it.

Answer (score 3):

The question is actually more generic than just VAR models and Granger causality.

In statistical modelling, you need a minimum sample size to be technically able to estimate model parameters. Once the minimum is passed, you can estimate the model and examine the parameter estimates and their confidence bounds.

The larger your sample, the narrower the bounds/the more precise the estimates. And conversely, the smaller the sample, the wider the bounds/the less precise the estimates. For a very small sample (just above the technical minimum), the bounds will be so wide/the precision will be so low that you will not be able to conclude anything useful about the underlying process (if you wish to do hypothesis testing) and the forecasts from the model will be highly inaccurate (if you care about prediction).

But to find out whether your sample size is sufficient, the easiest way is to actually estimate the model and see the results. You can then judge by yourself whether the precision is sufficient or not.

For the macroeconomic problem you are considering, you have 14 years of quarterly data, which is 56 observations. You also have two variables. If you use a VAR(5) model, you will have $1+2\times5=11$ parameters per equation (plus the error variance/covariance). That is $56/11\approx 5$ observations per parameter – not too bad. I would try and see how it goes.

Note 1: For increased estimation precision, you could also try regularized estimation, e.g. ridge regression, a.k.a. $L_2$ penalization. That might work best when the goal is forecasting. Meanwhile, inference (e.g. Granger causality testing) might be difficult to do after regularization.

Note 2: If the data you have are not adjusted for seasonality, you will need to build a more complicated model with more parameters (e.g. include quarterly dummy variables in each of the VAR equations). In your situation it could still be affordable: $56/(11+3)=4$ observations per parameter is still not too bad, hopefully. Also, the more explanatory variables there are, the more helpful regularization could be/the more relevant it becomes.

Comment: +1. I'd add that if seasonality is an issue, or even a side-issue, as it is often is, the number of years covered is a constraint on how well that is captured by a model. Finer time resolution increasing the sample size won't solve this. (Minimum number of years was in the original title; I don't think it's completely irrelevant.)

Comment: @NickCox, thanks. In macroeconomics, data often comes already adjusted for seasonality (unadjusted series are sometimes not even publicly available), so I am assuming this is not a problem (or not *the* problem of interest).

Comment: Indeed, but Granger causality has evoked interest outside economics, where on the contrary data are often not adjusted at all.

Comment: I think the idea of using regularized estimation is an unwise suggestion given that the goal is to carry out a Granger causality *test*. Or how do you propose the test to be conducted?

Comment: @hejseb, good point, I have edited my answer. The suggestion was meant primarily for forecasting (hence, it is just a note under the main part). Inference after regularization is an active research topic. I don't know exactly what results are available for ridge regression; that could be a new question. I guess for a fixed penalty intensity $\lambda$ the results are straightforward. It becomes difficult when $\lambda$ is selected from the same data set.